# Python program with multiple sockets with different port numbers from same script?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm attempting to send data via sockets to the same IP but via different ports.  These are the test scripts I've developed so far:

server:

```
# test_server.py

import socket
import select

# module-level variables ##############################################################################################

HOST1 = '127.0.0.1'
PORT1 = 65432

HOST2 = '127.0.0.1'
PORT2 = 65433

#######################################################################################################################
def main():

    sock1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock1.bind((HOST1, PORT1))
    sock1.listen()
    conn1, addr1 = sock1.accept()

    sock2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock2.bind((HOST2, PORT2))
    sock2.listen()
    conn2, addr2 = sock2.accept()

    conns = [ conn1, conn2 ]

    while True:

        readyConns, _, _ = select.select(conns, [], [])

        for conn in readyConns:
            data = conn.recv(1024)

            if not data:
                print('no data received')
            else:
                print('received: ' + data.decode("utf-8"))
            # end if

            conn.sendall(bytes('acknowledgement from server', 'utf-8'))
        # end for
    # end while
# end main

#######################################################################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

client:

```
# test_client.py

import socket
import time

# module-level variables ##############################################################################################

HOST1 = '127.0.0.1'
PORT1 = 65432

HOST2 = '127.0.0.1'
PORT2 = 65433

#######################################################################################################################
def main():

    myCounter = 1

    sock1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock1.connect((HOST1, PORT1))

    sock2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock2.connect((HOST2, PORT2))

    while True:
        # sock1 ############################################

        # send the original message
        messageAsStr1 = 'message 1-' + myCounter
        sock1.sendall(bytes(messageAsStr1, 'utf-8'))

        # receive the acknowledgement
        ack1 = sock1.recv(1024)
        if ack1 is None:
            print('error receiving acknowledgement on port 1')
        else:
            print('received: ' + ack1.decode('utf-8'))
        # end if

        time.sleep(2)

        # sock2 ############################################

        # send the original message
        messageAsStr2 = 'message 2-' + myCounter
        sock2.sendall(bytes(messageAsStr2, 'utf-8'))

        # receive the acknowledgement
        ack2 = sock2.recv(1024)
        if ack2 is None:
            print('error receiving acknowledgement on port 2')
        else:
            print('received: ' + ack2.decode('utf-8'))
        # end if

        time.sleep(2)

        myCounter += 1

    # end while

# end main

#######################################################################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I start `test_server.py` then `test_client.py`, `test_server.py` will start successfully, but upon starting `test_client.py` I get:

```
$ python3 test_client.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_client.py", line 66, in <module>
    main()
  File "test_client.py", line 23, in main
    sock2.connect((HOST2, PORT2))
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I don't understand why the 2nd connection won't go through, b/c if I divide `test_client.py` into 2 separate programs as follows:

```
# test_client1.py

import socket
import time

# module-level variables ##############################################################################################

HOST1 = '127.0.0.1'
PORT1 = 65432

#######################################################################################################################
def main():

    myCounter = 1

    sock1 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock1.connect((HOST1, PORT1))

    while True:
        # sock1 ############################################

        # send the original message
        messageAsStr1 = 'message 1-' + str(myCounter)
        sock1.sendall(bytes(messageAsStr1, 'utf-8'))

        # receive the acknowledgement
        ack1 = sock1.recv(1024)
        if ack1 is None:
            print('error receiving acknowledgement on port 1')
        else:
            print('received: ' + ack1.decode('utf-8'))
        # end if

        myCounter += 1

        time.sleep(2)

    # end while

# end main

#######################################################################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and:

```
# test_client2.py

import socket
import time

# module-level variables ##############################################################################################

HOST2 = '127.0.0.1'
PORT2 = 65433

#######################################################################################################################
def main():

    myCounter = 1

    sock2 = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock2.connect((HOST2, PORT2))

    while True:
        # sock2 ############################################

        # send the original message
        messageAsStr2 = 'message 2-' + str(myCounter)
        sock2.sendall(bytes(messageAsStr2, 'utf-8'))

        # receive the acknowledgement
        ack2 = sock2.recv(1024)
        if ack2 is None:
            print('error receiving acknowledgement on port 2')
        else:
            print('received: ' + ack2.decode('utf-8'))
        # end if

        myCounter += 1

        time.sleep(2)

    # end while

# end main

#######################################################################################################################
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Then start them in the order `test_server.py`, `test_client1.py`, `test_client2.py`, I get the expected results:

(first command prompt):

```
$ python3 test_server.py 
received: message 1-1
received: message 2-1
received: message 1-2
received: message 2-2
received: message 1-3
received: message 2-3
received: message 1-4
received: message 2-4
```

(second command prompt):

```
$ python3 test_client1.py 
received: acknowledgement from server
received: acknowledgement from server
received: acknowledgement from server
received: acknowledgement from server
```

(third command prompt):

```
python3 test_client2.py 
received: acknowledgement from server
received: acknowledgement from server
received: acknowledgement from server
received: acknowledgement from server
```

At this time my questions are:

1) Why does the 1st way (with the different port numbers in `test_client.py`) not work but it does if I split it into two scripts?

2) Is there a more elegant/robust way to achieve the same objective?  I should mention that in my final program I absolutely need the acknowledgement content and the flexibility to use different port numbers as well as IPs.

3) Another limitation of the above is in the 2nd case where it worked, I have to start the programs in the specific order `test_server.py`, `test_client1.py`, `test_client2.py`.  In the production version I'll eventually be making the order will vary.  Is there a recommended change to elegantly handle this?

Answer (score 1):

I can see why this would be confusing. Fortunately, the explanations are simple.

### Question 1 - blocking calls and race conditions

In your server script, when you tell it to accept(), your script "waits" (we say this function call is "blocking"). The rest of your server script has not even been looked at yet. Now you go run your client script, it connects on the first port and this causes the call in your server script to unblock and proceed. Now the "race" is on, will your server script execute the call to listen() and then accept() before your client makes its next call to connect()?? Maybe! But not likely, unless you put a sleep in your client. Then you will see it work every time.  But that is not the right solution.

### Question 2 - the "elegant" way

You really want to be waiting for connections on X number of ports simultaneously, not in series. The simple way to do this would be to use python multiprocessing module to launch parallel server threads of execution.  But, that is a heavy solution.

The right way really is to use select() which is the official means of saying "I'm just one process, but I want to listen for an wait for activity on multiple things (ports)".  So, you'll setup your multiple sockets and then give select the list of things you want to wait for.  It will block until there's activity on any one of those.  You do the work to process that and then loop back to select() again to block and wait for more activity (maybe next time on a different port, or maybe a new connection on the same port).

There is an important caveat, which may make select an 'advanced level' tool. As you process requests, be careful you don't spend too much time in processing, because all those other connections are waiting in the meantime. There are techniques to do this properly, such as managing all your socket and file io with libevent.

Using multiprocessing is more straightforward, but it will not scale as well as a well architected event-based design.  [Here's](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/apache-vs-nginx-practical-considerations) a discussion about an example of this, with Apache versus Nginx. Another example of the power of solutions based on event handling architecture is NodeJS, which famously runs everything in an event loop.

All this detail is to highlight, **since you said you are going to step up to a production implementation next** that there is a lot to think about.

**Best solution:** focus on solving your real problem, and let someone else design the server.  Learn to use gunicorn or wsgi (good servers already) and put your request processing in there.

### Question 3 - the right way to client

Naturally, you'll want to spiff up your client too.  The right way to do a client is of course to not expect everything to be perfect.  You are trying to connect to a faraway machine. The network might be down, the server might be offline, etc.  So, choose your strategy from among the popular choices for clients in general:

- fail (out of the script) with clear error to the user, they will retry if and when they want to by re-running your client script
- inform the user that you are pausing and will try again in 10 seconds.  Make X attempts (e.g. 10 attempts) then fail out of the (client) script.
- be a client with multiple options, automatically try other servers. If your problem domain warrants it, you can plan on architecting a grand solution with contingency plans. A great client automatically tries other servers if the first one is not answering (and a great service provides multiple available servers).

So, general answer: catch that exception and then decide what you want to do. Wait and retry in a loop, bail, or "other" ?